# I need to change javascript code for cookies. I am saving the input text but i need to save the div text not the input one

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I have code which changes the input to div and the second cookies code which save input text and show it but it show it in the input and I have to change it to div by pressing enter every time. How to save it in the div stadium to cookies? I know I just need to change the code below but how?

**EDIT:** Some JS imports were missing
HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="What's your name?"/>
    <div id="text"></div>
```

Javascript (in HTML file):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var name = Cookies.get('_username');
        if (name) {
            $('#name').val(name);
        }
        $('#name').keydown(function(){
            var inputName = $('#name').val();
            Cookies.set('_username', inputName);
        })
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#name').keydown(function(e){
     if(e.which==13){
        $('#name').hide();
        $('#text').html($('#name').val());
     }

  })
 });
    </script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is that you want to achieve ? Can you try to explain more clearly ?

Comment: I am saving to cookies the text in input field but I need to save the div text. and after refresh display the div default.

Comment: You want the text to show in the div as soon as you type ?

Comment: I will try to explain. The code I have published is doing this when a user enters his name the text box change to div. The cookies are saving the text in the text box and load it every time the page reloads. But what I need is to load the div not the text box every time the page loads. Do you understand me now?

Comment: I think I understand yes

Comment: I think all are there now

Comment: Was that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is what you want. The input is shown the first time you load the page, then when the user refresh the page, it is no longer shown as the cookie has already been set.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#text').hide();
        var name = Cookies.get('_username');
        if (name) {
            $('#text').html(name);
            $('#name').val(name);
            $('#name').hide();
            $('#text').show();
        }
        $('#name').keydown(function(){
            var inputName = $('#name').val();
            Cookies.set('_username', inputName);
        })
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#name').keydown(function(e){
      $('#text').html($('#name').val());
     if(e.which==13){
        $('#name').hide();
        $('#text').show();
     }

  });

  $('#text').dblclick(function(){
    $('#name').show();
    $('#text').hide();
  });
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yeah, nice thank you. And is some possibility how to edit that text back by double-clicking on that div.

Comment: I was just talking about that on double click it will edit the div and the cookie

Comment: @JosefKatič done, I edited my answer, there is code at the begining which is different so copy everything.